# Dialogs appear on wrong monitor with SQL Server Management Studio 2008

Tags: ssms, monitors

I am running SSMS 2008 on Windows 7 with a dual monitor setup (one large, one small). SSMS is running on the secondary monitor, but everytime a dialog is opened, the dialog is placed on the primary monitor instead. I've tried moving the dialog over, closing it, and then re-opening it, but it doesn't remember and goes back to the primary monitor.

This is really annoying for some of the designer dialogs, is there any way to fix this other than switching SSMS to the primary monitor? Is this a known bug with SSMS, or is it a problem with my particular setup?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think MS would consider that a "bug" so much as a "feature". There's plenty of software that does this; the fact that dual monitors aren't "in the home" yet keeps most programmers in the single monitor mindset (just my opinion). It's annoying and frustrating.

If you're willing to go another route, there's window manager programs which will move those screens around for you. I've never found one I'm willing to endorse however.